# Animate Bar Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to animate a bar plot, this is what I have so far:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
        for (int i=0; i<[data count]; ++i) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context,kOffsetX+i*kStepX, kGraphHeight-kOffsetY);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kOffsetX+i*kStepX, (kGraphHeight-kOffsetY)-(kGraphHeight-kOffsetY-kGraphTop)*([[data objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]/maxDataPoint));
        }
        CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        pathLayer.path=CGContextCopyPath(context);
        [self.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        pathAnimation.duration = 0.5;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = @0;
        pathAnimation.toValue = @1;
        [pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Since the path is bars from left to right, the "strokeEnd"-Animation gets a left-to right animation but I want a bottom to top animation, so the bars rise up. Do I need to change the Key of the animation or maybe another way to draw the path?

Thanks!